# Sumbit the form using ajax or not

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to understand if the first method of submitting the form is more secure than the second one:

**First method (no AJAX)**

a) post the password from view to controller

b) encrypt the password, pass it to the model

**Second method (using AJAX)**

a)post the password from view to controller using AJAX

b)encrypt the password, pass it to model

For the second method, I can see the password in console-network window of browser, that is why I think that this method is not secure.

Comment: Both post the password. You can md5 it on the client and send that instead?

Comment: Parsing of data should always be secured server side, and validated client side.. You're just passing data to a server, either through ajax, or a typical form post, doesn't matter.

Comment: It does matter- posting a plain text password is less secure than posting a hashed password (even though that hashing mechanism on the client can be reversed). That said, the hash that posts should NOT be the hash on the server.

Comment: Install [Firefox Tamper Data extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) and you'll see it using the first method also :-)

Comment: @Popnoodles, if you're passing a md5 hashed to the server and there you just compare the md5, there is no point in doing it, now the user password is md5(plain_text_password), see [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/76939/why-almost-no-webpages-hash-passwords-in-the-client-before-submitting-and-hashi)

Comment: I didn't suggest that, and I pointed out that that shouldn't be done.

Comment: Oops my bad, I missunderstood you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, encrypting the password yourself and network security are two different things.

When the user submits a form with a password, the password is sent in plaintext in an HTTP request. This is why secure websites use SSL, SSL encrypts the password in the **HTTP** layer. If you don't do that, no matter if you use encryption or not, someone could listen to the HTTP request and get the password from there.

Once the password has been sent over HTTP, the other thing you need to worry about is ensuring it is encrypted when you insert it into the database, if you don't make further requests, that's all that's necessary.

You can read more about SSL [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I realize that I should encrypt the password before sending it to database. My question is about the process of passing non-hashed password from the view to controller (perhaps it is called HTTP layer as you have noted). So, as I understand, I cannot secure that process unless I buy SSL certificate?

Comment: Yes, from "view to controller" you are using a new request, so it is HTTP. You do need SSL. You could make your own encryption in JavaScript, it would be safer than having nothing, but it would be easily crackable.

Comment: so it does not matter if I submit a password using AJAX or not (PHP only), someone can listen to the HTTP request and get the password from there.

Comment: Correct, I mean it's unlikely someone would listen in if you have a small site, but if you want to be 100% safe use SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Both the two methods are the same security level. Because the message aren't encrypted.

Download the Wireshark, install it and use (listen your Internet adapter), then if you send any form to the Internet, it will catch it, and you can see with it, thats only a plain text message to the server (and you can read your sent data without any external tools), in both case with some headers. If you want a more secure solution, use https which encrypt the message, this solution using SSL or TSL technology.

Both two examples easy to use on it the Men In The Middle attack, when the 3rd person can get all of your data, which you send to the server. (Of course there are a solution to use this attack with the https too to read the message, but it's a little harder)

And if I'm correct, there is a browser which is the firefox or the chrome, where you can see the HTTP page request too in the console, like a page request or a form submit. (In the build in console not in the firebug or other similar tools)